# Missing Data across shared computers

Tags: visual-studio, localdb

I have a setup where I have one computer at the office and another at my house, and the project data are being shared via OneDrive. This is purely for my own convenience and I only ever work on one computer at a time, shutting down Visual Studio when I'm not using it on either computer.

My current problem involves a project that is being synchronised via OneDrive but uses a SQL Server LocalDB database for development and testing but, despite the files being synchronised between the two computers, data that was inserted on one computer does not appear in queries run on the second computer.

Synchronisation only occurs once Visual Studio is shut down, since file locking prevents the process. I have verified that both the .mdf and the .ldf files are being copied (the file sizes and modification dates are correct). I have also physically copied the files via external harddrive to rule out the OneDrive synchronisation step, but the problem persists.

I have also verified that even after the files are copied, the inserted data is still present on the computer where the INSERT was done, but is not appearing when doing a SELECT on the second computer.

I was under the impression that LocalDB only used the .mdf and .ldf files, are there caching files somewhere else that I also need to synchronise?

All code and other project files are being synchronised just fine, it's only the database that is experiencing this problem.

I understand that this is probably a weird setup for most people, and I would never do this if I were in a team setting but I would appreciate some insight into what could be going wrong.

Comment: Are you just synchronizing the mdf/ldf files in the project folder? These files are probably not the ones that are updated on your first computer. What is the connectionstring used?

Comment: If I look in the SQL Server Object Explorer inside Visual Studio, right-click the database, select Properties, and then go to "Current Connection Parameters\Data File", the file path is the one for my .mdf file that is being synchronised. That's the first thing I checked on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble to anyone, I seem to have solved the issue myself.

Just for pure sanity, I tried to detach and then re-attach the .mdf file on the second computer (the one that was not picking up the INSERTed data) and got an error about the LocalDB instance being a version too old for the file.

Turns out the computer on which the INSERTs were done was running a v13 instance and upgraded the .mdf file to that version, while the other computer was running a v11 instance. Both computers are now running on the same instance version and the missing data is now showing.